# Bootstrap menu can't dropdown or use navbar-brand

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been sitting for quite some hours now trying to find the little bug that does that my dropdown or my icon (when mobile friendly) wont toggle down the menu.

Here is my html output:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">Forside</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/pladsen/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Pladsen <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="/pladsen/servicebygninger/">Servicebygninger</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have included the following bootstrap liberies:

```
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css][1]">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css][2]">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="[https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js][3]"></script>
```

I hope to get a second opinion on the stuff in hope of finding the bug.

Comment: If you know how to use your Browser's Development Tools (`ctrl+shift+i` or `f12`) you can inspect the console output, which will tell you if you're missing something. Check it now and see what it says (click the `Console` tab after opening the tools.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include Jquery too in order to make it work.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @McBoman did you include the Jquery before the bootstrap JS. Because when i paste your HTML inside JSFiddle, it works. http://jsfiddle.net/9cka1pd5/

Comment: Hehe thanks. I knew i was some stupid mistake. Thanks alot for the help.